# codekit-config.json keeps showing up in Tower, has anyone found a permanent fix using gitignore?

Tags: css, json, macos, codekit, git-tower

CodeKit will refresh every so often and config.json keeps showing up. I placed this file in gitignore but it still persists. Is there something wrong with this line in gitignore? I have posted a quick temporary fix for this issue, does anyone know of a good permanent fix using gitignore or know why mine is not working?

/www/app/webroot/public/codekit-config.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty good working solution if you do not update often. 
You can go to the settings of the project you are working on and check the auto-update configuration file option off.

This is a link showing you an example of the screen and the checked box for the auto-update config option.

[image]